# AJAXControlToolkit TabContainer-How to add and remove tab dynamically

Tags: asp.net

I am using `AjaxControlToolkit` version 4.1, .NET 4.0, VS2010,language-c#

Using the `TabContainer` control I want to add/remove tabs dynamically. Suppose I have some .aspx page. In 1st tab I have some `hyperlink` . While I will click on the `hyperlink` the corresponding .aspx page will open in a tab dynamically and also I can remove it.How to do it?  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Create**

> ```
> Create TabContainer
> ```

```
Dim tbContainer As New AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer
tbContainer.ID = "TabContainer1"
```

> ```
> Create TabContent
> ```

```
Dim tbContent As New Control
tbContent.ID = "tbContent_" & dt.Rows(i).Item("PRENR").ToString
```

> ```
> Create TabPanel
> ```

```
Dim tbPanel As New AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel
tbPanel.ID = "tbPanel_" & dt.Rows(i).Item("PRENR").ToString
tbPanel.HeaderText = "PREMIUM AMOUNT"
```

> ```
> Adding the controls to Page
> ```

```
tbContent.Controls.Add(dvEarner1)
tbPanel.Controls.Add(tbContent)
tbContainer.Tabs.Add(tbPanel)
tbContainer.Tabs.Add(tbPanel1)
tbContainer.Tabs.Add(tbPanel2)
tbContainer.Tabs.Add(tbPanel3)
tbContainer.Tabs.Add(tbPanel4)
tbContainer.Tabs.Add(tbPanel5)
pane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(tbContainer)
Me.MainAccordion1.Panes.Add(pane)
```

**Remove**

```
Me.TabContainer1.Tabs.Remove(tab)
```

Comment: Convert these code into C# using http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/